# Bower dependencies are not getting installed in Ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

[image]

I am working on ionic framework. I ran this command
bower install angular-local-storage --save

This shows me 
'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file

Answer (score 0):

Try running this

```
npm install -g bower to install bower
```